# Uninstall Caffe on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, uninstallation

I have installed [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html)  on my machine Ubuntu 16.04. It took a lot of memories and I can't even make it work after set up all the required dependencies.

I want to uninstall it (along with its dependencies). I have tried `make clean` but it seemed like nothing happened.

Could anybody help me out here, please? Thank you in advance.